# Can't get IP via DHCP in 19.04, but able to get if I use Windows

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip

I have a dual boot system (quite old machine) with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04. After registering my MAC address with the network admin, I can get an IP via DHCP if I log in to Windows, and I can access Internet. On Ubuntu, DHCP doesn't seem to work i.e.

sudo dhclient -v -s DHCP_server_IP my_interface_name

Times out. If I log in to Windows, get an IP via DHCP, run ipconfig /all, make a screenshot of it, then log in to Ubuntu and manually assign the default gateway, IP, subnet and DNS settings from the screenshot taken in Windows, then I can get Internet access in Ubuntu, but only till the DHCP lease granted in Windows (lease end time is printed in ipconfig /all) is valid. My network admin says that the server doesn't support Ubuntu. Is there a way for the server to know if it's talking to a Windows machine or a Ubuntu machine? If there is, then why can I get Ubuntu to connect after manual assignment of the settings taken in Windows? How can I avoid this cycling back to Windows? Would running a Windows VM on Ubuntu just to get the DHCP lease extended work? I am not very knowledgeable in these matters.

Edit 1: dhcpdump log is here https://pastebin.com/zSyC5u64

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96927/discussion-on-question-by-starscream-cant-get-ip-via-dhcp-in-19-04-but-able-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I seem to have found a solution. As described in [the comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96927/discussion-on-question-by-starscream-cant-get-ip-via-dhcp-in-19-04-but-able-to), examining the DHCP discovery packets with Wireshark for both Windows and Ubuntu indeed revealed a difference. Windows was sending some DHCP options different from those in Ubuntu, in particular option 60, vendor-class-identifier.

I then modified `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` so that my Ubuntu DHCP packets resemble the ones from Windows. It wasn't initially working, but then running `dhclient` manually with the `-v -cf` options (`-cf` allows to read the configuration file as an argument) showed that there was a syntax error in the `dhclient.conf` that I had modified due to a missing semicolon.

So far things are going smoothly, I can now see leases being granted and renewed in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`. Thanks to chili555 for taking so much time to help me!