# Ubuntu 22.04 Activation of Network Connection Failed

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dhcp

I have tried all the methods I have found but nothing works.

The connection I am trying to get to work is wired ethernet, the cable goes to the wall socket, back to a tp-link tl-sg108, which takes the connection from a TIM HUB+ ZTE H388X.
The system is a dual boot with Windows 10, it works perfectly fine there, although, not sure if it's just a coincidence, the first time I switched back after it stopped working on Ubuntu Steam warned its service was not running and I had to set it to automatic load on boot. I went back to Ubuntu after that, tried a bunch of fixes, nothing worked, I reverted the changed, rebooted, and it worked again till I switched back to windows and back to Ubuntu, hasn't worked since.
Everytime I go back to Windows the time is back by 2 hours, I need to disable and re enable auto time, Ubuntu manages that on its own instead, except now that it doesn't have a connection, so for example in the `syslog` grep there are some entries 2h ahead of some later entried because I noticed the time was off at some point after 11pm.
The motherboard is an Asus Sabertooth Z87 so the net card is a I217-V.
The connection worked fine for a few weeks on Ubuntu, it just started not working today.

On the router I tried:

- rebooting so the DHCP leases reset, in case the lease was only available for Windows if it was obtained there

On windows I:

- disabled fast boot;
- disabled wake-on-lan;

On Ubuntu I tried:

- telling NetworkManager to manage all connections by setting to true
  managed in `/etc/NetworkManager/NerworkManager.conf`;
- setting a dhcp client in the same file, both internal, dhclient, dhcpcd;
- netplan has the line telling it to let NetworkManaged to its thing in
  `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`;
- restarting NetworkManages with both `sudo service NetworkManager restart` and `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`
- creating an empty file at
  `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`;
- setting the IP, mask, gateway manually;
- `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` is empty;
- `/var/lib/dhcpcd` only has the wireless dhcp lease file and the
  `secret` file;

By running `sudo dhcpcd -T eno1` I sometimes saw it managed to get hold of an IPv6, which it used to actually connect but nothing more than just say it is connected. Ping doesn't get replies, and checking arp after ping only shows `<incomplete>` in the address which means it got nothing in reply.
dhclient also hangs.

What I haven't tried: this guy didn't explicitly explain what he did [Can't get IP via DHCP in 19.04, but able to get if I use Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162393/cant-get-ip-via-dhcp-in-19-04-but-able-to-get-if-i-use-windows)

Now for the usual commands outputs

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 04
   serial: 74:d0:2b:2c:b0:a4
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-37-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:28 memory:ef300000-ef31ffff memory:ef339000-ef339fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 9
   bus info: usb@3:6
   logical name: wlxc4e90a0658cc
   serial: c4:e9:0a:06:58:cc
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.15.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.3 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

`systemctl status NetworkManager` (I disabled manually the connection at the end to not interfere with the USB wifi)

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-06-11 01:56:01 CEST; 13min ago
   Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
Main PID: 1001 (NetworkManager)
  Tasks: 3 (limit: 38371)
 Memory: 12.1M
    CPU: 640ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
         └─1001 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
giu 11 02:04:03 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905843.1941] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
giu 11 02:04:03 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905843.1944] device (wlxc4e90a0658cc): Activation: successful, device activated.
giu 11 02:04:05 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905845.5149] dhcp4 (wlxc4e90a0658cc): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.3
giu 11 02:04:05 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905845.5155] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
giu 11 02:04:05 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905845.5157] policy: set 'TIM-19358435' (wlxc4e90a0658cc) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
giu 11 02:04:09 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905849.7524] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
giu 11 02:04:24 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905864.5081] device (eno1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
giu 11 02:04:24 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905864.5098] audit: op="device-disconnect" interface="eno1" ifindex=2 pid=2467 uid=1000 result="success"
giu 11 02:04:24 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905864.5220] device (eno1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
giu 11 02:04:24 Phantom NetworkManager[1001]: <info>  [1654905864.5392] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
```

`systemctl status dhcpcd`

```
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-06-11 01:56:00 CEST; 1h 13min ago
   Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
Process: 1002 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1100 (dhcpcd)
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 38371)
 Memory: 1.5M
    CPU: 324ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
         └─1100 /usr/sbin/dhcpcd

giu 11 02:41:10 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: eno1: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 02:41:10 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: wlxc4e90a0658cc: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 02:47:02 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: eno1: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 02:47:02 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: wlxc4e90a0658cc: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 02:56:07 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: eno1: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 02:56:07 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: wlxc4e90a0658cc: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 03:01:27 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: eno1: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 03:01:27 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: wlxc4e90a0658cc: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 03:04:03 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: eno1: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
giu 11 03:04:03 Phantom dhcpcd[1100]: wlxc4e90a0658cc: Router Advertisement from fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
```

`sudo lspci -nnk`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b] (rev 04)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection I217-V [1043:859f]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

`ip -6 neigh show`

```
fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30 dev wlxc4e90a0658cc lladdr 98:00:6a:a6:7a:30 router STALE
fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30 dev eno1 lladdr 98:00:6a:a6:7a:30 router STALE
```

`ip -4 neigh show`

```
192.168.1.11 dev wlxc4e90a0658cc  FAILED
192.168.1.1 dev wlxc4e90a0658cc lladdr 98:00:6a:a6:7a:30 REACHABLE
```

`nmcli`

```
wlxc4e90a0658cc: connected to TIM-19358435
    "D-Link DWA-131 Nano"
    wifi (rtl8xxxu), C4:E9:0A:06:58:CC, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.3/24
    route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 303
    route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 303
    route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 600
    inet6 fe80::9990:2313:9f3a:28ce/64
    inet6 fe80::29e5:3afd:ce7b:9742/64
    route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
    route6 fe80::/64 metric 256

eno1: connected to Wired connection 1
    "Intel I217-V"
    ethernet (e1000e), 74:D0:2B:2C:B0:A4, hw, mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::48c6:f95d:829c:925d/64
    route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

lo: unmanaged
    "lo"
    loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
    servers: 192.168.1.1
    domains: home
    interface: wlxc4e90a0658cc

    servers: fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30
    interface: wlxc4e90a0658cc

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.
```

`nmcli device show`

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlxc4e90a0658cc
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C4:E9:0A:06:58:CC
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     TIM-19358435
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.3/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 303
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 303
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9990:2313:9f3a:28ce/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::29e5:3afd:ce7b:9742/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::9a00:6aff:fea6:7a30

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         74:D0:2B:2C:B0:A4
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/13
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::48c6:f95d:829c:925d/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

`nmcli con show`

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE          
TIM-19358435        6c09dd30-1f42-40ae-a76a-24e0e9f43f0e  wifi      wlxc4e90a0658cc 
Wired connection 1  ea97f513-3101-44a4-98a9-4cebaea410ae  ethernet  eno1
```

`nmcli con show "Wired connection 1"`

https://pastebin.com/VrLsjVwq

`sudo dhcpcd -T eno1`

```
DUID 00:04:41:9d:bf:20:d7:da:11:dd:ae:ff:74:d0:2b:2c:b0:a4
eno1: IAID 2b:2c:b0:a4
eno1: soliciting an IPv6 router
eno1: soliciting a DHCP lease
eno1: probing for an IPv4LL address
eno1: using IPv4LL address 169.254.230.155
interface='eno1'
pid='9102'
protocol='dhcp'
reason='TEST'
ifcarrier='up'
ifflags='4163'
ifmtu='1500'
ifwireless='0'
dhcpcd exited
```

`arp -a -v`

```
? (192.168.1.11) at <incomplete> on wlxc4e90a0658cc
H388X.home (192.168.1.1) at 98:00:6a:a6:7a:30 [ether] on wlxc4e90a0658cc
Entries: 2  Skipped: 0  Found: 2
```

`sudo arpsend -D -e 192.168.1.1 eno1`

```
arpsend: can't get iface 'eno1' address : Cannot assign requested address
```

`ifconfig`

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::48c6:f95d:829c:925d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 74:d0:2b:2c:b0:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1221  bytes 128481 (128.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 874  bytes 146162 (146.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xef300000-ef320000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 22543  bytes 1701449 (1.7 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 22543  bytes 1701449 (1.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxc4e90a0658cc: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::9990:2313:9f3a:28ce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 fe80::29e5:3afd:ce7b:9742  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether c4:e9:0a:06:58:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 41887  bytes 32973913 (32.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 32570  bytes 6583725 (6.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ip addr show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 74:d0:2b:2c:b0:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s25
inet6 fe80::48c6:f95d:829c:925d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlxc4e90a0658cc: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether c4:e9:0a:06:58:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlxc4e90a0658cc
   valid_lft 81932sec preferred_lft 81932sec
inet6 fe80::9990:2313:9f3a:28ce/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::29e5:3afd:ce7b:9742/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip r`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlxc4e90a0658cc proto dhcp src 192.168.1.3 metric 303 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlxc4e90a0658cc proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlxc4e90a0658cc proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 303
```

`route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         H388X.home      0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlxc4e90a0658cc
default         H388X.home      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxc4e90a0658cc
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlxc4e90a0658cc
```

`systemctl restart dhcpcd@eno1.service`

```
Failed to restart dhcpcd@eno1.service: Unit dhcpcd@eno1.service not found.
```

`sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd@eno1.service`

```
Failed to restart dhcpcd@eno1.service: Unit dhcpcd@eno1.service not found.
```

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep dhcp4`

https://pastebin.com/EEp5GgPe